# Updating an item property within IEnumerable but the property doesn't stay set?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables: Transactions and TransactionAgents. TransactionAgents has a foreign key to Transactions called TransactionID. Pretty standard.

I also have this code:

BrokerManagerDataContext db = new BrokerManagerDataContext();

```
var transactions = from t in db.Transactions
                   where t.SellingPrice != 0 
                   select t;

var taAgents = from ta in db.TransactionAgents
               select ta;

foreach (var transaction in transactions)
{
    foreach(var agent in taAgents)
    {
        agent.AgentCommission = ((transaction.CommissionPercent / 100) * (agent.CommissionPercent / 100) * transaction.SellingPrice) - agent.BrokerageSplit;
    } 
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = taAgents;
```

Basically, a TransactionAgent has a property/column named AgentCommission, which is null for all TransactionAgents in my database.

My goal is to perform the math you see in the `foreach(var agent in taAgents)` to patch up the value for each agent so that it isn't null.

Oddly, when I run this code and break-point on `agent.AgentCommission = (formula)` it shows the value is being calculated for AgentCommissision and the object is being updated but after it displays in my datagrid (used only for testing), it does not show the value it calculated.

So, to me, it seems that the Property isn't being permanently set on the object. What's more, If I persist this newly updated object back to the database with an update, I doubt the calculated AgentCommission will be set there.

Without having my table set up the same way, is there anyone that can look at the code and see why I am not retaining the property's value?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>`s do not *guarantee* that updated values will persist across enumerations. For instance, a `List` will return the same set of objects on every iteration, so if you update a property, it will be saved across iterations. However, many other implementations of `IEnumerable`s return a new set of objects each time, so any changes made will not persist.

If you need to store and update the results, pull the `IEnumerable<T>` down to a `List<T>` using `.ToList()` or project it into a new `IEnumerable<T>` using `.Select()` with the changes applied.

To specifically apply that to your code, it would look like this:

```
var transactions = (from t in db.Transactions
                    where t.SellingPrice != 0 
                    select t).ToList();

var taAgents = (from ta in db.TransactionAgents
                select ta).ToList();

foreach (var transaction in transactions)
{
    foreach(var agent in taAgents)
    {
        agent.AgentCommission = ((transaction.CommissionPercent / 100) * (agent.CommissionPercent / 100) * transaction.SellingPrice) - agent.BrokerageSplit;
    } 
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = taAgents;
```

Comment: Oh. Thats nice to know. So, I need to .ToList() my enumerable before I foreach over them?

Comment: Yes, that way the values will be stored locally in the List instead of temporarily in a disposed-of object.

Comment: -1 This answer is simply *wrong*. You definitely can change object properties that are accessed via `IEnumerable`. The `List` itself implements `IEnumerable`....

Comment: On another look, you're right - I guess the more correct description is an `IEnumerable` does not *guarantee* that updating its values will persists across enumerations.

Comment: I did go crazy with this :) Thanks so much.

Comment: @ken2k Imagine code `from t ... select new MyDTO { X = x, Y = y }` every time you enumerate such a sequence you are creating new class that doesn't see previous changes. I have such a bug in production and after that we required that all methods that return `IEnumerable` must call `ToArray` or `ToList` to prevent lazy evaluation.

Comment: @eouw0o83hf what is strange here is  that we are enumerating EnityFramework `DbSet`s. Generally EF should cache objects loaded from DB (and I may assume that change tracking is also enabled) and every iteration should return the same objects. Am I wrong here? EDIT: I found my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707970/why-does-entity-framework-6-x-not-cache-results

Answer (score 4):

Specifically, the problem is that each time you access the IEnumerable, it enumerates over the collection.  In this case, the collection is a call to the database.  In the first part, you're getting the values from the database and updating them.  In the second part, you're getting the values from the database again and setting that as the datasource (or, pedantically, you're setting the enumerator as the datasource, and then that is getting the values from the database).

Use .ToList() or similar to keep the results in memory, and access the same collection every time.

Comment: Wow. So the problem is much worse than eow0o83hf described. I understand that its sort of "readonly" but the enumerable is essentially wiping out the values as the collection is read.

Comment: It's not so much that it's wiping out the values, but that it's reading from a different collection.  (In simple (but not technically correct) terms, it creates a new "collection" every time you enumerate it)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using LINQ to SQL, if EnableObjectTracking is false, then the objects will be constructed new every time the query is run.  Otherwise, you would be getting the same object instances each time and your changes would survive. However, like others have shown, instead of having the query execute multiple times, cache the results in a list. Not only will you get what you want working, you'll have fewer database round trips.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to locate the item in the list that I wanted to modify, extract the copy, modify the copy (by incrementing its count property), remove the original from the list and add the modified copy. 
                    var x = stats.Where(d => d.word == s).FirstOrDefault();
                    var statCount = stats.IndexOf(x);
                    x.count++;
                    stats.RemoveAt(statCount);
                    stats.Add(x);

Comment: This is very inefficient and bad coding practice. You really should not use LINQ for this, especially with lists. just use the normal operator[].

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful to rewrite your LINQ expression using lambdas so that we can consider the code in more explicit terms.

```
//Original code from question
var taAgents = from ta in db.TransactionAgents
               select ta;
```

```
//Rewritten to explicitly call attention to what Select() is actually doing
var taAgents = db.TransactionAgents.Select(ta => new TransactionAgents(/*database row's data*/)});
```

In the rewritten code, we can clearly see that `Select()` is *constructing* a *new object* based on each row returned from the database. What's more, this object construction occurs *every time* the `IEnumerable` `taAgents` is iterated through.

So, explained more concretely, if there are 5 `TransactionAgents` rows in the database, in the following example, the `TransactionAgents()` constructor is called a total of 10 times.

```
// Assume there are 5 rows in the TransactionAgents table
var taAgents = from ta in db.TransactionAgents
               select ta;

//foreach will iterate through the IEnumerable, thus calling the TransactionAgents() constructor 5 times
foreach(var ta in taAgents)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"first iteration through taAgents - element {ta}");
}
// these first 5 TransactionAgents objects are now out of scope and are destroyed by the GC


//foreach will iterate through the IEnumerable, thus calling the TransactionAgents() constructor 5 MORE times
foreach(var ta in taAgents)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"second iteration through taAgents - element {ta}");
}

// these second 5 TransactionAgents objects are now out of scope and are destroyed by the GC
```

As we can see, all 10 of our TransactionAgents objects were *created* by the *lambda* in our `Select()` method, and do *not* exist outside of the scope of the `foreach` statement.

Comment: Not exactly. The method-syntax equivalent is `db.TransactionAgents.Select(ta=> ta)`.