# C# failing to set property inside IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Seen a weird bit of behaviour in some C# code that I'm at a loss to explain. Could be I'm missing an important bit of understanding, so hoping someone out there can switch on the light for me.

Got a block of code that looks like this:

```
    IEnumberable<myObject> objects = GetObjectsFromApiCall();

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(objects.ElementAt(i).SubObject.Title))
            {
                SubObject sub = GetSubObjectFromDatabase((long)objects.ElementAt(i).SubObject.Id);
                if (sub != null)
                {
                    objects.ElementAt(i).SubObject.Title = sub.Title;
                }
            }
        }
```

When you step through it, everything about this code seems to work properly. The "objects" collection is populated as expected. "sub" is fetched as collected and has a full set of expected properties, including a populated Title property. No errors are thrown during execution.

But ... the SubObject.Title property (which just has standard get; set; code) that exists in each Object stubbornly remains empty.

I'm at a loss. Anyone explain what's going on?

EDIT: For those who suggested I shouldn't use a for loop and ElementAt, I started with a foreach loop but thought it might be the source of the problem because it was fetching a new SubObject each time round. Fixed now, thanks to your help, and the ForEach restored.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: There you go: [Updating an item property within IEnumerable but the property doesn't stay set?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9104212/93732)

Comment: This code has the potential to be so slow it is not even funny.

Comment: Could you copy/paste the *actual* code you have, not something that *looks* like the *actual* code?

Comment: It works, but you might be comparing different copies of the data. Can you confirm that both `myObject` and the type of the `SubObject` property (or field) are `class` types, as opposed to `struct` (or `interface`) types? If the method call `GetObjectsFromApiCall()` generates a new copy of the data each time it is called, you're only modifying the copy. The "original" data will be unchanged in that case.

Comment: @ChaosPandion I assume you meant that in the spirit of helpful co-operation. I know it could be slow, but it won't end up handling more than 10 objects at a time.

Comment: @MattThrower - I really did although my delivery was terrible. My goal was to comment so those who answer will remember to add a special note regarding the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would fix it this way:

```
var objects = GetObjectsFromApiCall().ToList();
```

Then you could keep the loop as is (it works), or optimize it a bit using foreach and some Linq as suggested by other answers, but it does not really matter: the problem was that you attempted to change an element on an IEnumerator<> as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9104212/93732) pointed by @Ahmet Kakıcı.

Comment: -1 This is actually wrong. There is no problem in modifying elements returned by an `IEnumerable`. Actually, when you're using `foreach` after a `ToList()`, you're precisely using an `IEnumerable`, as `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. One problem could be the *deferred execution* of a DB query, but it's certainly not because of the simple presence of the `IEnumerable` interface...

Comment: You are right, I read too fast... The problem is not the IEnumerable but the way it is implemented. That's why using ToList() makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ken2k Correct. See my answer for examples where I modify the items returned by an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
List<myObject> objects = GetObjectsFromApiCall().ToList();

foreach(var obj in objects.Where(o => string.IsNullOrEmpty(objects.SubObject.Title)).ToList())
{
    var subObject = GetSubObjectFromDatabase(obj.SubObject.Id);
    if(subObject == null) continue;

    obj.SubObject.Title = subObject.Title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not use `ElementAt()` for this kind of code, use

```
foreach (var o in objects)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.SubObject.Title))
    {
        o.SubObject.Title = ...;
    }
}
```

Also you should note that if your method returns a dynamic `IEnumerable` then every time you call `objects.Something()` the API is called again and a fresh copy is retrieved. If this is the case, you should copy the enumerable into a list using `.ToList()` method.

There is also a way of not putting a copy in the list - by creating a dynamic enumerator like this:

```
objects = objects.Select(o =>
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.SubObject.Title))
    {
        o.SubObject.Title = ...;
    }
    return o;
});
```

As for the value not being set correctly (if previous things did not help) - try adding a `throw new Exception(value)` in the setter for `Title` property - see if that is being called with the correct value.

Comment: "First of all, you should not use ElementAt() for this kind of code." Why?

Comment: .NET will enumerate every time using `Enumerator.MoveNext()` for `i` times to get the value. it is way slower than `list[i]` approach.

Answer (score 1):

I guest the function GetObjectsFromApiCall looks like following:

```
public IEnumberable<myObject> GetObjectsFromApiCall(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
         yield return new myObject();
    }
}
```

If I'm right, every time you call objects.ElementAt(i) function to get the object, you will get a new object by "`yield return new myObject()`".

Comment: That's a good theory. I was thinking of posting an example like that.

Comment: oh, you should change "objects.ElementAt(i).SubObject.Title = sub.Title;" to " var obj = objects.ElementAt(i).SubObject; obj.Title = sub.Title;"

Comment: Regarding your comment: What would it change?

Comment: i wrote a test like `objects.ElementAt(i).SubObject.Title = sub.Title`, it cann't be compiled.

Comment: Was `SubObject` a property whose type was a mutable `struct`?

Answer (score 1):

But how do you check if the `Title` property is changed? Do you call `GetObjectsFromApiCall()` again? Or do you `foreach` through the same `objects` instance again?

An `IEnumerable` instance may create and yield new objects each time it is "enumerated". So here's a simple example for illustration. For the example, define:

```
class SomeObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Then we will consider two types of "source", first an array, and then an iterator block defined like this:

```
  static IEnumerable<SomeObject> GetSomeSequence()
  {
      yield return new SomeObject { Title = "Alpha", };
      yield return new SomeObject { Title = "Beta", };
      yield return new SomeObject { Title = "Gamma", };
  }
```

Then test it this way:

```
  static void Main()
  {
      IEnumerable<SomeObject> thingsToModify;

      // set source to an array
      thingsToModify = new[] { new SomeObject { Title = "Alpha", }, new SomeObject { Title = "Beta", }, new SomeObject { Title = "Gamma", }, };

      foreach (var t in thingsToModify)
          Console.WriteLine(t.Title);

      foreach (var t in thingsToModify)
          t.Title = "Changed!";

      foreach (var t in thingsToModify)
          Console.WriteLine(t.Title);    // OK, modified


      // set source to something which yields new object each time a new GetEnumerator() call is made
      thingsToModify = GetSomeSequence();

      foreach (var t in thingsToModify)
          Console.WriteLine(t.Title);

      foreach (var t in thingsToModify)
          t.Title = "Changed!";          // no-one keeps these modified objects

      foreach (var t in thingsToModify)
          Console.WriteLine(t.Title);    // new objects, titles not modified

  }
```

Conclusion: It's perfectly possible to modify the state of a mutable object which belongs to the source we're iterating over. But some types of `IEnumerable` sources yield new copies of the data each time they are called, and then it's useless to make modifications to the copy.