# Why are IEnumerable Projections not Immutable?

Tags: c#, linq

Assuming my `Awesome` class has a property `Bazinga`, which is a `String` with the default value of "Default value", I could go:

```
    var enumerableOfAwesome = Enumerable
        .Range(1, 5)
        .Select(n => new Awesome());

    foreach (var a in enumerableOfAwesome)
        a.Bazinga = "New value";
```

As you may already be aware, enumerating the `enumerableOfAwesome` again will not make you happy, if you expect to find your "New value" strings safely tucked away in all the `Bazinga`. Instead, outputting them to the console would render:

> Default value
>   Default value
>   Default value
>   Default value
>   Default value

[(.NET Fiddle here)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L0TeVp)

This is all well and dandy from some deferred execution point-of-view, and that issue has been discussed already before, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104181/updating-an-item-property-within-ienumerable-but-the-property-doesnt-stay-set) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294499/c-sharp-failing-to-set-property-inside-ienumerable). My question however is why the enumerator implementations do not return immutable objects; If persistence over several enumerations is not guaranteed, then what use is there of the ability to set values, save making people confused?

Maybe this isn't a very good question, but I'm sure your answers will be enlightening.

Comment: ToList() or ToArray() are your friends in this situation.  And understanding what they do may help you to understand what's going on.

Comment: Because there's no magical immutability wrapper in C#, the enumerable is just returning an instance of a type that defines its own state and mutability.

Comment: A LINQ query is really just a set of instructions that define what should be executed on a certain collection and which return a new collection. If you execute it twice, you will perform the instructions on the collection twice -- that's it. If you don't store those results in a collection and use that collection, you will start from the same point twice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My question however is why the enumerator implementations do not return immutable objects

How would you expect them to do that? They're sequences of whatever type is used - what would you expect to happen with something like:

```
var builders = new string[] { "foo", "bar" }.Select(x => new StringBuilder(x));
```

? Would you expect it (whatever "it" is in this case) to create a new type automatically with the same API as `StringBuilder`, but magically making it immutable? How would it detect mutations?

Basically, what you're asking for is infeasible - you can have a sequence where the element type is mutable, so while iterating through it you can mutate the object that the yielded reference refers to. Expecting anything else is unrealistic, IMO.

Comment: I'm not sure how to react to "infeasible". I realize that it would pose a challenge, but yes "magically making it immutable" would be fine by me. Should I read your answer as "it's a stupid notion" or as "there is no practical solution"?

Comment: @OskarLindberg, Its both a bad notion and impractical. If you want your `Awesome` to be immutable, you have to write it that way. For example you could create a class called `AwesomeReadOnly` that can be cast from the `Awesome` type that is an immutable object. How you implement it is up to you, its beyond what I believe a compiler should be doing behind the scenes to mangle your code. There are plenty of cases when you want this to be mutable too.

Comment: The solution for wanting to easily project into something immutable is also already covered by anonymous types.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: Not really - if you have an anonymous type where one of the members is mutable, it's still only *shallow* immutability - change my example to `new { Builder = new StringBuilder(x) }` and you'd still be able to do `item.Builder.Append("xx")`

Comment: @OskarLindberg: While Entity Framework etc are "somewhat magic", LINQ to Objects is anything but - and that's the way I like it. The compiler behaves in a very predictable way, and the actual code implementing LINQ to Objects is pretty simple. I really wouldn't want something creating type facades, possibly cloning objects "just in case" etc in the background. If you want immutability, you go do that yourself.

Comment: I'm sure you realize I don't want unpredictable behavior in code any more than you do - magic was your suggestion. I never claimed to actually _want_ immutability; "Go do that yourself" is obviously fine - regardless of assuming mutability or immutability to be the default - but that's besides the point. In any case, I'll accept your answer as: "Because there's no practical way of achieving that (and besides, it might not be a brilliant idea)".

Comment: @OskarLindberg: It wasn't a suggestion - I was asking what you were expecting. I generally *don't* expect magic, and if I see magic I try to dig into it :)

Answer (score 0):

Enumerators are not meant to provide immutability. They are a way to loop through collections like in looping through standard arrays with indexes. As you can access underlaying objects this means you can change them. And yeah immutability in C# is more of a new thing in terms of collections and this would be unexpected and impossible to implement in Enumerators.

Comment: Just because you can loop them doesn't mean they are mutable. You can loop through immutable arrays/lists/enumerables too.