# Why does Entity Framework 6.x not cache results?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, entity-framework-6

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the caching that `DbContext` and `DbSet` does but I was under the impression that there was some caching that would go on. I'm seeing behavior that I wouldn't expect when I run the following code:

```
var ctx = CreateAContext();
var sampleEntityId = ctx.SampleEntities.Select(i => i.Id)
                                       .Single(i => i == 3); //Calls DB as expected
var cachedEntityId = ctx.SampleEntities.Select(i => i.Id)
                                       .Single(i => i == 3); //Calls DB unexpectedly
```

What's going on here? I thought that part of what you get from `DbSet` is that it would first check the local cache to see if that object exists before querying the database. Is there just some sort of configuration option I am missing here?

Comment: @Jonesy I'll update it provide a more clear example.

Comment: @Adriano Unfortunately that answer is 5 years old and refers to a much older version of EF.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What [@emcas88 is trying to say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21708204/304832) is that EF will only check the cache when you use the `.Find` method on `DbSet`.

Using `.Single`, `.First`, `.Where`, etc will not cache the results unless you are using second-level caching.

Comment: Do you know of any resources for implementing second level caching in EF6 or any projects that have already done it?

Comment: If you google it you should find some. I vaguely recall one on codeproject, though it was not for EF6, it may work and is definitely a good place to start. A better solution would involve not having to execute the same query a second time.

Comment: My question on this stems from a concern that if I query my `DbContext` and load some entities in a `DbSet`, then run a stored procedure that has side effects on that `DbSet`, I want to make sure my "stale" entities aren't there anymore. Sounds like I don't need to worry about that.

Comment: EF **WILL CACHE** the results of `.First` due to [Performance Considerations for Entity Framework 4, 5, and 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#2). warm query uses cached data. Also i have a code that uses `.Where` and it reads from cache. Likely EF caches `.Single` too

Comment: @mjalil I think you are confusing results caching with metadata, view, and materializer caching. Only `.Find` will cache actual query results in the first-level cache.

Comment: It is still basically caching. Mindblowing, confusing things can happen because of it. For instance, if you `Add()` a new entity that wasn't created using `Create()`, then select out that entity, you will get back the exact same object you added, and it will be missing dynamic proxies and all that. So, sharing a DbContext across multiple bits of code that add and select things can become quite confusing. The solution is **always use `Create`**, but it is extremely confusing behavior.

Comment: @AdamModlin a second level cache resource I used for EF6 is http://entityframework-plus.net/tutorial-query has worked quite well for my needs; read up on it and test drive it.

Answer (score 36):

This is because the implementation of the extensor methods, use the Find method of the context

```
contextName.YourTableName.Find()
```

to verify first the cache. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @MailmanOdd i mean use the Find method of the context. This method check the cache first.

Comment: +1, this is actually the correct answer. I don't think less than perfect English should be a reason for a downvote.

Comment: Not at all. Next time update your answer instead of adding to it in the comments, and people should be more likely to retract their downvotes.

Comment: While I understand that `Find` will check `DbSet<T>.Local` first, I don't believe this really answers my question.

Comment: Yes...good answer - here is a link to a good explanation with more details. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx

Comment: Find can be used ony when you are looking for an object by its primary key value

Comment: Does using `.Find()` only have cache per instance of`DBContext`. Or is there a static shared cache across all instances of `DbContext()`?

Answer (score 26):

Sometimes I use my extension method:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace System.Data.Entity
{
    public static class DbSetExtensions
    {
        public static TEntity FirstOrDefaultCache<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> queryable, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition) 
            where TEntity : class
        {
            return queryable
                .Local.FirstOrDefault(condition.Compile()) // find in local cache
                   ?? queryable.FirstOrDefault(condition); // if local cache returns null check the db
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
db.Invoices.FirstOrDefaultCache(x => x.CustomerName == "Some name");
```

You can replace FirstOrDefault with SingleOrDetfault also.

Comment: I like this solution. Just a little feedback: you missed the "this" before "DbSet<TEntity> queryable", and witting "Where(condition).FirstOrDefault()" is the same as ".FirstOrDefault(condition)". Thanks for sharing cryss.

Comment: Very interesting. But would this work with Lazy Loading too?

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at [EF Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936), you will find answer there:

> Note that DbSet and IDbSet always create queries against the database
>   and will always involve a round trip to the database even if the
>   entities returned already exist in the context. A query is executed
>   against the database when:
>
> - It is enumerated by a **foreach** (C#) or **For Each** (Visual Basic) statement.
> - It is enumerated by a collection operation such as `ToArray`, `ToDictionary`, or `ToList`.
> - LINQ operators such as `First` or `Any` are specified in the outermost part of the query.
> - The following methods are called: the `Load` extension method on a `DbSet`, `DbEntityEntry.Reload`, and `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`.

Answer (score 7):

EF6 doesn't do results caching out of the box.  In order to cache results, you need to use a second level cache.  See this promising project on CodePlex:

[Second Level Caching for EF 6.1](http://efcache.codeplex.com/)

Keep in mind that if data changes on the db, you won't immediately know about it.  Sometimes this is important depending upon the project.  ;)

Comment: You are talking about *2nd-level* cache. What he is asking is *1st-level* cache, I believe. :)

Comment: This answer appears to be wrong. See http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/, for example.

Comment: 1st-level cache is the default if you require the second level cache then you could use something like http://entityframework-plus.net/tutorial-query

Answer (score 0):

It  is very clear on MSDN.
Please note what is find

```
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/][1]


using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    // Will hit the database
    var blog = context.Blogs.Find(3);

    // Will return the same instance without hitting the database
    var blogAgain = context.Blogs.Find(3);

    context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Id = -1 });

    // Will find the new blog even though it does not exist in the database
    var newBlog = context.Blogs.Find(-1);

    // Will find a User which has a string primary key
    var user = context.Users.Find("johndoe1987");
}
```

Comment: This question was asked over 5 years ago. That documentation did not exist.