# Query about Entity Framework caching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

Lets say I have these three methods:

```
public Customer GetCustomerByCustomerGuid(Guid customerGuid)
{
    return GetCustomers().FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerGuid.Equals(customerGuid));
}

public Customer GetCustomerByEmailAddress(string emailAddress)
{
    return GetCustomers().FirstOrDefault(c => c.EmailAddress.Equals(emailAddress, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}

public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    return from r in _customerRepository.Table select r;
}

//_customerRepository.Table is this:
public IQueryable<T> Table
{
    get { return Entities; }
}
```

Would this cause a query to the database each time I make a call to `GetCustomerByEmailAddress()` / `GetCustomerByCustomerGuid()` or would EF cache the results of `GetCustomer()` and query that for my information?

On the other hand, would it just cache the result of each call to `GetCustomerByEmailAddress()` / `GetCustomerByCustomerGuid()`

I am trying to establish the level of manual caching I should go to, I really dislike running more SQL queries than are absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will result in a call to the database every time. I actually asked a similar question earlier today and you can see more here: [Why does Entity Framework 6.x not cache results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707970/why-does-entity-framework-6-x-not-cache-results)

Comment: Ah I see. Out of interest how did you see if EF was hitting the DB or not?

Comment: I used SQL Server Profiler to trace all calls to my database.

Comment: I knew something like that existed but couldn't see it in SQL Express (which I use at home). I'll look a little deeper.

Comment: I guess that's not part of SQL Express. But it will definitely call the database every single time. I was dealing with this today unfortunately.

Comment: `.Find()` it is then. Thanks for the information, I'll mark this as the answer (edit: in 4 minutes :) ).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it'll query the database every time.

Your concern should be to optimize your code so that it only queries for and returns the record you need. Right now it's pulling back the entire table and then you're filtering it with `FirstOrDefault()`.

Change `public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()` to `public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()` to make it more efficient.

Comment: That's not how LINQ to EF works. The LINQ Provider is smart enough to translate `FirstOrDefault()` into `select top 1`. Basically, any query methods used for a LINQ to EF query that have equivalent SQL functions will be executed as SQL in favor of operating on the result set in C#.

Comment: It would if it were returning an IQueryable rather than IEnumerable.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - That was my understanding as well. The query is generated based on the full LINQ query.

Comment: @AnthonyChu - In my case `_customerRepository.Table` is `IQueryable<>` but the poster would not of known that.

Comment: @AnthonyChu how do you know the type returned by `GetCustomers()`?

Comment: It's in the code listing above. It needs to be changed to `public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()`

Comment: @AnthonyChu - Would the call to `.Table` (see my edit) make this Ok as it returns `IQueryable` or do both need to return it?

Comment: @AnthonyChu oh I see what you're saying and you're actually right. However, I wouldn't suggest changing the `GetCusomters()` method, I would suggest getting rid of it because it's completely useless and worst case, ensures you have bad performance by causing only the code within that method to be run in SQL while the other methods that operate on it are just using LINQ to Objects on the initial result.

Comment: Details here on IEnumerable vs IQueryable... http://stackoverflow.com/a/2876655/3199781

Comment: Interesting. You are not only ignoring Anthony's advice but someone even downvoted his correct answer.

Comment: Also, to my point. Why create a helper method that is only 1 line? How is that helpful?

Comment: @Stilgar that was my fault but I cannot unvote unless he edits :(

Comment: @Stilgar - Querying advice isn't ignoring it (and I am unsure why you thought I was), I just won't jump at every answer straight away. Based on the comments here though, it all makes sense.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - You are right, the `GetCustomers()` is kinda useless at the moment. The reason I made it was to become a wrapper for getting cached customers as well (I have a comment in my local code to do so but ommitted from the question)

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad. I should have provided more details.

Comment: @webnoob if your intent is to cache the result I suggest adding a property to the class, in the getter you can check if the reference is null and execute the query if it is (lazy loading) otherwise, return it. Then everywhere in your code just use that property as the starting point of your query and get rid of `GetCustomers()`. If you want to get results every time, get rid of `GetCusomers()` and begin every query with the code in `GetCustomers()`.