# foreach with OfType does not modify object property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

This code:

```
foreach (var d in data.OfType<FtpData>().Where(fd => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fd.LocalPath)))
{
    d.LocalPath = Url.Content(d.LocalPath);
}
```

When the loop finishes if I examine 'data' the value of LocalPath is still the original, it has not changed. Why? Does the OfType() create a copy of the object?

The loop is executing correctly - I can breakpoint inside it and see the property value change - but once out of the loop the change is lost.

UPDATE:

If I do this:

```
var data2 = data.ToList();
```

and change the foreach to use data2 instead then it works. I don't quite understand why though, but looking in the debugger the actual type of 'data' is System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator ...which may have something to do with it?

Comment: Is `FtpData` a class or a struct?

Comment: I think you need to include how `data` is declared and populated in order for us to assist further on this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is **NOT** for modifying items. It is for iterating items.Use List or Array (`.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`).

Comment: This doesn't apply here since he's not modifying the collection but modifying an element.

Comment: The OP is modifying an element in the collection.. not the collection itself.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, u cant modify items, iterating with IEnumerable

Comment: You can modify items .. you can't modify the collection.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, can you give an example?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, in case of data source of type `List<T>` it will work, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104181/updating-an-item-property-within-ienumerable-but-the-property-doesnt-stay-set, so `IEnumerable` still not for modifying stored data.

Comment: So you understand my concern with your answer. You've flat out said it can't be done.. yet, it clearly can.