# Update item in IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I need to update a value in a IEnumerable list.

Here is a brief IEnumerable example:

```
IEnumerable<string> allsubdirs = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
```

Now if I want to add a timestamp to each item, this doesnt work:

```
allsubdirs.Select(a => a = a + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss")).ToList();
```

Neither does this:

```
foreach (var item in allsubdirs)
            item = item + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss");
```

I made it work like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> newallsubdirs = allsubdirs.Select(a => a + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss")).ToList();
        allsubdirs = newallsubdirs;
```

but this somehow seems like cheating. Whats the proper way of doing this please?

Comment: `IEnumerable` is *readonly*. You can not modify it. If you want to modify collection, then consider to change it to `List`.

Comment: Perhaps using a List<string> would be more appropriate?

Comment: Use a proper class instead of strings, even a Tuple<string,string> or Tuple<string,DateTime> will do. Iterate the result of your query and set the second item to the timestamp

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Judging by the variable names they are trying to append the datetime to a folder name

Comment: @Sayse then the OP already has the correct results after `Select` but throws them away because they are never stored

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Which is what the code that does work does

Comment: @Farhad Jabiyev not because its readonly... readonly collection means that you cannot alter the collection, (delete, add elements) but if the collection hosts ref types like object, you can alter them since you have a ref

A problem here is IEnumerable doesn't guarantee that updated values will persist across enumerations 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104181/updating-an-item-property-within-ienumerable-but-the-property-doesnt-stay-set

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*.  Linq queries return a *new* collection (or an itearator on top of the source collection) based on projections, filters etc.  So your choices are:

- Save the "new" collection back to the variable (or a new variable, if necessary):

  ```
    allsubdirs = allsubdirs.Select(a => a + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss")).ToList();
  ```
- Use a writable interface like `IList<T>` and a `for` loop:

  ```
    IList<string> allsubdirs = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

    for(int i=0; i<allsubdirs.Count; i++)
        allsubdirs[i] = allsubdirs[i] + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss");
  ```

The main difference is that `Select` *does not modify the original collection*, while the `for` loop does.

My opinion is that the `Select` is cleaner and is not "cheating" - you're just adding a projection on top of the original collection.

Comment: `a => a = a + "_" + ...` is unnecessary. You are assigning to a function argument `a`, which would have no effect on the original enumerable and then returning the right hand side of the assignment. Just `a => a + "_" + ...` would have been enough.

Comment: if you have objects in your IEnumerable instead of strings then Select changes a bit:
        `Select(a => { a.SomeStringProperty =  "new value"; return a; });`

Answer (score 5):

[D Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081897/d-stanley) has answered it correctly. I would like to add to his answer since the title is `Update item in IEnumerable` implying only a single item is to be updated.

As [D Stanely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081897/d-stanley) explained in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29676417/9411757):

> Linq is for querying, not updating.

and

> Use a writable interface like IList and a for loop

For updating a single item, you can retrieve the index of the item to be updated and use that index to update it.

For example:

```
IList<string> allsubdirs = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
int index = allsubdirs.IndexOf("a");
allsubdirs[index] = "d";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first try

```
allsubdirs.Select(a => a = a + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss")).ToList();
```

returns a new `IEnumerable` but does not change the old one. For that use

```
allsubdirs = allsubdirs.Select(a => a + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss")).ToList();
```

Comment: Or simply store the result in another variable. It doesn't have to replace the original and it makes the code cleaner

Comment: The assignment shouldn't be done here; it's not actually doing anything but it gives the false impression that it is, hence the OP's confusion.

Comment: @Servy: actually I think this cleared it up for me! Thank you

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well if this were executed inside a method and the caller expect the parameter to be modified, it is correct to replace the variable

Comment: @JimAho but the parameter *wouldn't* be modified. Not unless it was a `ref` or `out` and the code replaced the *parameter itself*, not the variable.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the existing answers, an `IEnumerable` collection cannot be modified by trying to assign a new value to one of its elements.

However if the elements contained in the collection are of a mutable type, you could modify them. But for your example that is not possible because a `string` is immutable.

So if you want to modify the existing elements in an `IEnumerable`, the element itself should be a type that supports modification operations, as in the below example.

```
public class MyItem
{
    private string _value;

    public MyItem(string content)
    {
        _value = content;
    }
    public void Append(string other)
    {
        _value += other;
    }
    public void ReplaceWith(Func<string, string> replacer)
    {
        _value = replacer(_value); 
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
IEnumerable<MyItem> allsubdirs = new List<MyItem>() { new MyItem("a"), new MyItem("b"), new MyItem("c") };

foreach (var item in allsubdirs)
        item.Append("_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss"));
```

Comment: "if the elements contained in the collection are of a mutable type, you could modify them." - Exactly.  I use foreach directly on LINQ result IEnumerable to modify reference types.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var result= allsubdirs.Select(x => String.Format("{0}_{1}", x,
                                      DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss")));
```

If you don't want to store it in another variable, consider using `ToList()`.