# Modify an entry in a nested IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, get, set, ienumerable

I am currently trying to modify an entry which is stored in a nested `IEnumerable`, 
I am currently trying to write a unit-test where I need to test the case where

```
var original = new IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>();
//fill test with all kind of values
var test = original.clone()
test.First().First() = 3;
```

but I cannot seem to change/Set the value of the nested IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676220/update-item-in-ienumerable), “Linq is for querying, not updating”. In your code you are querying for the first element of the first enumerable but when you assign a value to it that will not get written back to the enumerable.

Using a writable interface such as `IList<T>` should do the trick:

```
var original = new List<IList<int>>();
//fill test with all kind of values
var test = original.clone()
test[0][0] = 3;
```

Comment: IList interface cannot be instantiated. replace it with List: var original = new List<IList<int>>();