# Why can't the properties of elements within an IEnumerable<> be updated?

Tags: .net, reference, ienumerable

I came across this answer that explains *that* it cannot be done, but I am wondering *why*.

[Updating an item property within IEnumerable but the property doesn't stay set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104181/updating-an-item-property-within-ienumerable-but-the-property-doesnt-stay-set)

Take this code for example:

```
var MyClasses = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }.Select(id => new MyClass { Id = id });

MyClass BobClass = MyClasses.FirstOrDefault(_mc => _mc.Id == 3);

BobClass.FirstName = "Bob";

Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, FirstName: {1}", BobClass.Id, BobClass.FirstName);

foreach (var MyClass in MyClasses)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, FirstName: {1}", MyClass.Id, MyClass.FirstName);
}
```

- I create a collection.
- I get element with Id == 3 from the collection using `FirstOrDefault()`.  This gets me a reference to the element within the collection.
- I set its FirstName property to Bob
- When I iterate through the list, FirstName is still null.

I don't understand how this works.  I clearly get a reference to the original object, but it's almost as if `FirstOrDefault()` is giving me but a *copy* of the object rather than a reference.  I can update the copy, but it obviously doesn't persist to the original because they're two entirely separate entities.

**Update**

Wow, this is interesting:

```
BobClass = MyClasses.FirstOrDefault(mc => object.ReferenceEquals(BobClass, mc));
```

Bob returns `null`...?  Gotta say... I'm definitely stymied here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyClasses is an IEnumerable. This will be executed every time you access it. This in itself does not make it impossible to update one of the classes. But... You create NEW instances of MyClass every time. These obviously will have uninitialized properties. If you add .ToList() you will get the behavior you expect.

Comment: DUH... and they're not instantiated until the iterator gets started, so I am creating new objects every time I start using the iterator.  Thanks.

Comment: It makes sense when you start looking at lambdas as anonymous delegates.  The `new MyClass()` expression exists in a delegate that has not yet been invoked, so it's going to execute `new MyClass()` on every iteration when the delegate is invoked.