# Why can't I replace each object's property in a list within loop?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Why can't I replace each object's property in an IEnumerble list within loop?

```
 foreach(var group in groupedClassOptions){

            var gradeNo = group.GroupName.Split(' ')[1];

            if (gradeNo != grade0_name)
            {
                var groupTotal = temp.Where(t => t.grade.ToString().Equals(gradeNo)).First().total;
                group.GroupName += " (" + groupTotal + " students)";
            }
            else
            {

                var prepGroupTotal = temp.Where(t => t.grade.ToString().Equals("0")).First().total;
                group.GroupName += " (" + prepGroupTotal + " students)";
            }
        }
```

after i exit this loop the property **GroupName** of each **group** element was expected to change but it didn't.

### Example data - groupedClassOptions

[GroupName: Grade Prep,

Options  : [Prep A (23 students), Prep B (21 students)],

GroupName: Grade 1,

Options  : [1 A (23 students), 1 B (21 students)],

GroupName: Grade 2,

Options  : [2 A (23 students), 2 B (21 students)],

]

This is just so you can get the idea, pls ignore any syntax errors.
Now i want to replace **GroupName: Grade 1** with **GroupName: Grade 1 (x students)**

**Implementation of groupedClassOptions**

```
var groupedClassOptions = dataClass.GroupBy(x => x.grade).Select(x => new OptionGroupVM()
        {
            GroupName = "Grade " + (x.Key == 0 ? grade0_name : x.Key.ToString()) /*+ " (" + (groupTotal.Where(t => t.grade.ToString().Equals(x.Key)).First().total) + " students)"*/,
            Options = x.Select(y => new OptionVM()
            {
                Value = y.classID.ToString(),
                Text = x.Key == 0 ? grade0_name + y.classname.Substring(1) + " (" + y.total + " students)" : y.classname + " (" + y.total + " students)"
            })
        });
```

Comment: maybe `gradeNo == grade0_name`?

Comment: I strongly suspect in your if condition. Check value of gradeNo and grade0_name and make sure, it would execute if-inside code

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside the loop and press F5.

Comment: it is executing i have debugged when inside loop works as expected but when exits nothing has been replaced. I am sharing the full code

Comment: groupedClassOptions could return a copy.

Comment: @qxg ok so  how do i get that copy?

Comment: It's possible `group` is a copy of original object, and modifying it doesn't change original one. Could you share the implementation of `groupedClassOptions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `groupedClassOptions` to list using `ToList()` method which makes your object inside `list` to be updatable.

```
var groupedClassOptions = dataClass.GroupBy(x => x.grade).Select(x => new OptionGroupVM()
        {
            GroupName = "Grade " + (x.Key == 0 ? grade0_name : x.Key.ToString()) /*+ " (" + (groupTotal.Where(t => t.grade.ToString().Equals(x.Key)).First().total) + " students)"*/,
            Options = x.Select(y => new OptionVM()
            {
                Value = y.classID.ToString(),
                Text = x.Key == 0 ? grade0_name + y.classname.Substring(1) + " (" + y.total + " students)" : y.classname + " (" + y.total + " students)"
            })
        }).ToList();
```

Now, update object inside above list.

The reason behind not updating object inside IEnumerable is posted in [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104181/updating-an-item-property-within-ienumerable-but-the-property-doesnt-stay-set):

> IEnumerables do not guarantee that updated values will persist
>   across enumerations. For instance, a List will return the same set of
>   objects on every iteration, so if you update a property, it will be
>   saved across iterations. However, many other implementations of
>   IEnumerables return a new set of objects each time, so any changes
>   made will not persist.

Comment: wow awesome tip. thanks!